# Website not displaying properly in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+

Tags: html, iphone, responsive-design

I am totally new to iPhone coding. I have a website, and it's working perfect in all mobiles and desktop versions, **except** iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.

Problem is, it is not showing full page, i.e. width and height not coming 100%

Can any one guide me what changes I should do in code? Thanks a lot!

[Here](http://www.shopwings.com.au/delivery_fees) is URL.

Comment: I answered before looking at your site, its not responsive at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `viewport` meta. Define this in your `head`.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This would fit the content to whatever the `device-width` is.

Comment: Tx that help a bit. 

But problem now is, when I open it in mobile, it first shows me site, which is tooo much zoomed. I have to zoom out it & than it fits to screen... any solution for this?

Comment: Set the `initial-scale` to some smaller value. Ex- 0.5, 0.75.... See yourself, what works best.

Comment: Place the code somewhere within the<head></head> tag